# Python - Is there a built-in publisher/consumer pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I was looking for a very simple, inline, publisher/consumer, or an event pattern, builtin in Python, is there such thing?

For example:

db/user.py

```
def create(**kwargs):
  user = db.put('User', **kwargs)
  publish('user.created', user)
```

admin/listeners.py

```
@consume('user.created')
def send_email_on_signup(user):
  send_admin_mail(f'New user signup {user.name}')
```

Comment: Not built in. But if you want to go with a good library, I have had success using [rxpy](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html). This library has been implemented in like 20 different languages, which allows concepts to be easily shared when migrating to different languages/ frameworks.

Comment: This seems like it's a bit much. Why don't you just import `send_email_on_signup` and call it instead?

Comment: @MichaelM. it's a very simple example, in reality I have several asynchronous side effects that don't fit in where they are triggered

Answer (score 0):

For in-process event queue, the asyncio event loop can act as a very simple in-process event handling pattern.

Many web frameworks like Django and FastAPI comes with their own event handling patterns though. Django has signals and FastAPI has background task. But it's also pretty common to use something like Celery with both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in module called queue which provides a thread-safe way to implement the producer-consumer pattern.

The queue module provides the Queue class, which implements a thread-safe FIFO queue. The Queue class has methods for adding items to the queue (put()), removing items from the queue (get()), and checking whether the queue is empty or full (empty(), full()).

In the producer-consumer pattern, producers add items to the queue, and consumers remove items from the queue. The queue module provides a convenient way to synchronize access to the queue so that producers and consumers don't interfere with each other.